# Copying data from a list of multiple standardised workbooks to the active workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I'd like to for each object in a table, open the workbook from a file path in column 4 and copy about 52 cells (which will be in the same place in each workbook) into my active spreadsheet.

Table looks like this

Code is rudimentary because I thought if I could solve the first copy, I could replicate it further

```
        Set tbl = Sheet1.ListObjects("OTJ")  
        For Each cell In tbl.DataBodyRange.Columns(4).Cells
        WB = cell.Value
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=WB
    Set x = Workbooks.Open(WB)
    Set y = ActiveWorkbook
    v = x.Sheets("Sheet2").cell("D70")
Cells(2, 5) = v
    x.Close
```

I keep getting the subscript out of range error, please help

Comment: Get rid of the `Workbooks.Open Filename:=WB`. `Set x = Workbooks.Open(WB)` is correct and all you need.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear where you want to put the extracted data, but something along these lines should work:

```vb
Dim tbl As ListObject, cell As Range, wb As Workbook
Dim wsData As Worksheet

Set wsData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")  'or wherever...

Set tbl = Sheet1.ListObjects("OTJ")

For Each cell In tbl.DataBodyRange.Columns(4).Cells

    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(cell.Value)
    wsData.Cells(2, 5).Value = wb.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("D70").Value
    wb.Close False 'no save
    
Next cell
```

Comment: Hello Tim, Many thanks for this! I am not sure why but I got subscript error from using .Range 
For posterity I got around this by using .cells instead which also added an option to automate the cell selection. For example .cells(70, 4) for D70.  Many thanks again pal :-)